# Configure Jenkins to alert Slack after certain amount of time?

Tags: jenkins, slack

I have a jenkins pipeline that goes through dev, stage and prod.  At each stage the user has manually trigger the next stage of the pipeline.  We frequently forget to do this.  Is there any a way to configure the jenkins slack plugin to alert in a channel after something has been in a stage for a certain period of time? Or something similar to that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make something similar work by using the timeout option from Jenkins DSL to expire the blocked task.

This does use an exception for controlling the flow of the implementation. Using exceptions in this way is not "best practice" in my experience, but it does achieve the result I wanted.

```
def result;

while (!result?.trim()) {
  try {
    timeout (activity: true, time: 2) {
      result = input "Enter some value"
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    //Timeout Exception
    echo "No value entered within time period.  Sending Reminders."
    //Other work goes here, or calls appropriate notify function.
  }
}

echo result
```

Best of luck